# Dynamic SQL execution error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to execute dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure which throws an error even though it works fine with static SQL. Just wondering what's the best way to run dynamic SQL inside my stored procedure?

Comments :-

This sql is present inside one stored procedure SP2 and its being called from another stored procedure SP1 where the temp table is being created and used in SP2. The static sql works fine but when I try to run dynamically through stored procedure it fails.

Execution :-

```
execute sp_executesql @inputsql_1, N'@newInputTableName NVARCHAR(100)';
```

Error :-

```
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
```

Dynamic SQL :

```
SET @inputsql_1 = 'INSERT INTO #tlocationinput(locationsid,contractsid,locationid,locationname,address,city,areascheme,intarealevel1,strarealevel2,strarealevel3,strarealevel4,strareabriefnamel1,strareabriefnamel2,strareabriefnamel3,strareabriefnamel4,zip9,subarea2,cresta,latitude,longitude,streetnumber,streetname,streettype,prefix,suffix,streettypeex )
 SELECT  locationsid
       , contractsid
       , locationid
       , locationname
       , address
       , city 
       , COALESCE( NULLIF(areascheme,0),
                   CASE WHEN LEN(i.postalarea) > 0 THEN 1003
                        WHEN LEN(i.subarea) > 0  THEN 1001
                        WHEN LEN(i.area) > 0 THEN 1000
                     END
                  ) AS areascheme
       , COALESCE(l.country, CASE WHEN i.country in (''US'') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS intarealevel1
       , s.area AS strarealevel2
       , COALESCE(l.subarea, i.subarea) AS strarealevel3
       ,  REPLICATE(''0'',5) + SUBSTRING( i.postalarea,1,5 ) AS strarealevel4      
       , COALESCE(l.country_cd, i.country) AS strareabriefnamel1
       , COALESCE(l.state_cd, i.area)   AS strareabriefnamel2
       , null AS strareabriefnamel3
       , null AS strareabriefnamel4
       , CASE WHEN LEN(i.postalarea) > 5 THEN i.postalarea ELSE NULL END AS zip9
       , subarea2
       , cresta
       , latitude
       , longitude
       , streetnumber
       , streetname
       , streettype
       , prefix
       , suffix
       , streettypeex
FROM @newInputTableName i
left outer join 
     airgeography.dbo.tcountrylookup l on ( i.country = l.country_cd and  ( REPLICATE(''0'',5) + SUBSTRING( i.postalarea,1,5 ) ) = l.postal_area)
left outer join 
     #statelookup s on ( i.country = s.country_cd and s.state_cd = i.area );'
```

Comment: Adding the error may help.

Comment: I added the error msg in the question

Comment: What is your interpretation of that message?

Comment: Try `execute sp_executesql @stmt = @inputsql_1, N'@newInputTableName NVARCHAR(100)';`

Comment: Write out the SQL that's in @inputsql_1 before you execute it.  see if you see anythign wrong..

Comment: This doesnt work...

Comment: The value in the variable newInputTableName doesnt get parsed when its being used in the variable inputsql_1

Comment: What datatype are you using for @inputsql_1?

Comment: I am using VARCHAR(8000)

Comment: Use `NVARCHAR(...)`. The error message is pretty much saying you should...

Comment: Thank you... NVARCHAR worked for me.....